# Android local video server

Tags: android, websocket, video-streaming, localserversocket

I am trying to make a local web server using socket that will stream a video.

Following is my code for server:

```
class VideoStreamServer {

        public void startServer() {
            outFile = new File(outFilePath);
            Runnable videoStreamTask = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                        sb.append( "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n");
                        sb.append( "Connection: close\r\n" );
                        sb.append( "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n" );
                        sb.append( "Content-Length: " + outFile.length() + "\r\n" );
                        sb.append( "\r\n");


                        System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect.");
                        while (true) {
                            Socket client = socket.accept();
                            System.out.println("Thread Started");
                            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(outFile);
                            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                            int length;
                            //System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                            os.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                            while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1){
                                os.write(data,0,length);
                            }
                            os.flush();
                            os.close();
                            socket.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            Thread streamServer = new Thread(videoStreamTask);
            streamServer.start();
        }

    }
```

So the problem is whenever I hit url in web browser following exception is thrown.

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:508)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:270)
     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:139)
     at com.example.sachinchandil.myapplication.VideoStreamDownloaderFragment$VideoStreamServer$1.run(VideoStreamDownloaderFragment.java:285)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
     at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
     at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:156)
     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:466)
    ... 7 more
```

And if i download this file using `HttpUrlConnection` all bytes frame are download except last and same exception is thrown.

Comment: After a client connected you should first read from the inputstream before you write to the outputsream i think.

Comment: @Greenapps if u see through the code care fully u can find that too.

Comment: You read the input stream after you write the header. Client maybe is not ready to read yet (it could be blocked by its first write operation). Also I have experience with client app that tried to open second connection after reading the header from first connection, but first connection wasn't closed immediately (it was MediaPlayer implementation on some specific Android device). Your code is blocked with one connection and doesn't accept another. Probably you will need another thread for communication after you get Socket client, so you can wait for another socket.accept().

Comment: `if u see through the code care fully u can find that`. No. You aren't. Why would i otherwise tell you?

Comment: sorry for that. Ok so you mean i should create request pool for more than one request? if so how would it help? i mean if second request is initiated then also client will get headers first and so on. same process will continue. please correct me and give your inputs over these queries.

Comment: Request pool? Where are you talking about? Until now you talked about one request. The comments you became were about reading from the inputstream at the wrong moment. Two people mentioned that.

Comment: Of course your server should handle every client in its own thread. Otherwise you will block.

Comment: This is what i understood from your comment. right now i want to process only one request for a testing purpose later on i will manipulate is as per requirement. I am still stuck here, how would you suggest me to write headers in outputStream to resolve this problem.

Comment: Two people told you to first read from the inputstream. After that do the writing to the outputstream.

Comment: may be there is a misunderstanding. i am getting this inputStream from local file not from server. I think you are assuming it coming from server.

Comment: 'client.getOutputStream()'. So you write to the output stream of the socket Now before you do that read all from the inputstream of the socket: client.getInputStream()

Comment: No i have not read client's inputstream

Comment: ¿????????????? Yes i know. That's why i said you should. Did you adapt your code already? Tell us the results. Strange that you did not do all already.

Comment: Thanks for you replay, It is the first time i am working on Video streaming using Socket so i haven't done it already. What result do i tell you?