# Video streaming firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am developing a app that need to play video in it from firebase

**Problem**

When the video is getting loaded it consumes lot of data and take time 
So i want to load video in parts like youtube does 
So how to implement this feature of loading video in parts

Comment: Where your videos are uploaded? Firebase, Youtube or any other place

Comment: Videos are uploaded to firebase

Comment: Hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371224/download-video-along-with-playing

Comment: Could anyone else help